# How to use boost::latch?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am trying to use boost::latch in my program to block waiting until all the threads finish or time out. My code is as follows. ctpl is a thread pool library adopted from https://github.com/vit-vit/CTPL.

```
#include <boost/thread/latch.hpp>
#include <CTPL/ctpl.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    ctpl::thread_pool outer_tp(100);
    ctpl::thread_pool inner_tp(5, 5000);

    auto out_func = [&inner_tp](int outer_id, int outer_invoke_idx) {
        int num_batch = 20;
        boost::latch latch_(num_batch);

        auto func = [&latch_, &outer_invoke_idx](int inner_id, int inner_invoke_idx) {
            try {
                std::cout << "outer: " << outer_invoke_idx << ", inner: " << inner_invoke_idx << endl;
            } catch (exception &ex) { cout << "error: " << ex.what() << endl; }
            latch_.count_down();
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < num_batch; ++i) {
            inner_tp.push(func, i);
        }

        latch_.wait_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) outer_tp.push(out_func, i);
    outer_tp.stop(true);

    return 0;
}
```

> g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp  -lboost_system -lpthread -lboost_chrono -lboost_thread

However I get the following error message.

> bool boost::latch::count_down(boost::unique_lock&): Assertion `count_ > 0' failed.

If I use latch_.wait() instead of latch_.wait_for() or set very long wait time, the code works without error. Hence I guess 'time out' leads to this error issue. Does any one know how to fix the error.

Comment: Well, isn't it that if the timeout is too short, your inner threads do not have enough time to synchronize on the latch and the outer thread goes away and dies before the inner thread reaches the `count_down`. And when it does reach the `count_down`, it is filled with zeroes and hence the assert triggers?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be few issues with your code. I think that referring to `latch_` in inner thread by reference is one of them. Replacing that with `shared_ptr` to `boost::latch` fixes that. Another issue is similar but with  `outer_invoke_idx`. Fixing those and waiting for `inner_tp` to finish seems to make your test work just fine.

Here is modified test case that works for me:

```
#include <boost/thread/latch.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <CTPL/ctpl.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    ctpl::thread_pool outer_tp(100);
    ctpl::thread_pool inner_tp(5, 5000);

    auto out_func = [&inner_tp](int outer_id, int outer_invoke_idx) {
        int num_batch = 20;
        auto latch_ = std::make_shared<boost::latch>(num_batch);

        auto func = [latch_, outer_invoke_idx](int inner_id, int inner_invoke_idx) {
            try {
                std::cout << "outer: " << outer_invoke_idx << ", inner: " << inner_invoke_idx << endl;
            } catch (exception &ex) { cout << "error: " << ex.what() << endl; }
            latch_->count_down();
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < num_batch; ++i) {
            inner_tp.push(func, i);
        }

        latch_->wait_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) outer_tp.push(out_func, i);

    outer_tp.stop(true);
    inner_tp.stop(true);
    std::cout << "EXITING!!!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was getting all sort of crazy memory errors when I tried to implement my own latch on stack using `std::condition_variable`, then things improved when I replaced it with `boost::latch`: I got a consistent assertion failure. Thanks for pointing to `std::shared_ptr`, my sleep deprivation was preventing me to see how to fix the race condition at the end of the functions. Is this some sort of know issue with barriers and latches?